# ValueAnimator/Expand/Collapse view not giving correct height

Tags: android, animation, view, layoutparams

I have a search bar that expands when icon is clicked in toolbar. Now, everything is cool when it is expanded, everything works fine, the thing that is not good is that the height isnt good when the search bar is collapsed. The toolbar upon collapsing search bar has bigger height than it had. Here is the code:

```
private void expand(View view) {
    //set Visible
    view.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

    final int widthSpec = View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED);
    final int heightSpec = View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED);
    view.measure(widthSpec, heightSpec);

    ValueAnimator mAnimator = slideAnimator(0, view.getMeasuredHeight(), view);
    mAnimator.start();
}

private ValueAnimator slideAnimator(int start, int end, final View view) {

    ValueAnimator animator = ValueAnimator.ofInt(start, end);
    animator.addUpdateListener(new ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator valueAnimator) {
            //Update Height
            int value = (Integer) valueAnimator.getAnimatedValue();
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams layoutParams = view.getLayoutParams();
            layoutParams.height = value;
            view.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
        }
    });
    return animator;
}


private void collapse(final View view) {
    int finalHeight = view.getHeight();

    ValueAnimator mAnimator = slideAnimator(finalHeight, 0, view);

    mAnimator.addListener(new Animator.AnimatorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAnimationStart(Animator animation) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animator) {
            //Height=0, but it set visibility to GONE
            view.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationCancel(Animator animation) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationRepeat(Animator animation) {

        }
    });
    mAnimator.start();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Everything is good here, check where you call method if you are changing background or any other property of the toolbar.